# How to check if an azure resource is already in use using azure CLI?

Tags: azure, asynchronous, concurrency, azure-cli, azure-cli2

Let's assume that an azure resource, ex "storage account" is being updated!
at the same time if I run a command like

```
az storage account update --default-action Allow --name MyStorageAccount --resource-group MyResourceGroup
```

It will throw an error

> The request failed due to conflict with a concurrent request or something similar

So before running such command, how can I check if the resource is being used like being updated using Azure CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the what I'm looking for inspired by the above answer at this link [az resource wait](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest#az-resource-wait) 

So it will be something like

```
az resource wait -n "RESOURCE_NAME" -g "RESOURCE_GROUP" --resource-type "RESOURCE_TYPE" --updated
```

Comment: probably makes sense to at least upvote the answer if it helped you?

Comment: you did not at the time of writing of this comment

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`az resource show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest#az-resource-show) to show everything about an Azure resource.

So in your case you would do:

```
az resource show -n "RESOURCE_NAME" -g "RESOURCE_GROUP" --resource-type "RESOURCE_TYPE"
```

Comment: How is this gonna tell me if it's being updated right now?

Comment: resource status should be updating, not succeeded